# How to do two different graphics plotting in parallel using C#

Tags: c#, plot

I am developing the GUI in C# using picturebox, button, and check box.I need to plot two different plots in parallel using one text file on an image. The image first reads in a picture box.  The rest of the program has to be executed in the following way:

1. Reads text file contains the data points which have to be plotted.
2. After clicking the button the program execution started with the plotting of the First graphic (rectangular dot), however when the check box is checked the second graphic (continuous dots--path plot) plotting started in parallel with the first graphic.
3. when the check box is unchecked the second graphic stopped plotting and disappears.(As Both of the graphics style using the same text file).

I need help what to do in this case, should I create the separate thread for check box for this parallel plotting??

please help me where I am mistaken? And pardon my horrible English

Comment: _g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();_ - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Comment: Your post is a little unclear. So you have a number of coordinates in a text file and want to plot them onto one or two pictureboxes. Should the plot happen in one go or in an animated fashion? Should the 2nd pbox show the same image or only the first or last or which part of the data? is there any user interaction?

Comment: Also: We need to see the real code or a version we can use to reproduce the issue. Your code doesn't compile. (Missing curlies etc..). And it leaks all over the place, unless the missing dispoing code is left off..

Comment: Hi TaW, Actually I am using only one PictureBox here in my program, And I want to plot two graphics on an image, The image read it on the picture box. Then the click button activates the program execution and plots first graphic as a point plotting and the check box is check the track of this point (i.e. the second graphic) starts plotting in parallel with first graphic (which is the point plot) and when the check box is unchecked the track plotting stopped and should be disappear . Again when the check box is checked the tracking plot started in continuity with the first graphic again.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view, the easiest way would be to reload the image into the picture box again and then redraw the first graphics object on it. So, the second one 'disappears'.

An additional thread makes no sense, because drawing **must** occur on the UI thread only (Windows general rule for GDI+, WinForms, WPF).

Such basic drawing as in your example is very fast.

**Edit:**

```
namespace PictureBoxDrawing
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private Bitmap _bmpImage;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnLoad(e);

      _bmpImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Image.jpg");
      InitializePictureBox(_bmpImage);
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DrawPictureBox(pictureBox1, 10, 10, checkBox1.Checked);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DrawPictureBox(pictureBox1, 10, 10, checkBox1.Checked);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      InitializePictureBox(_bmpImage);
    }

    private void DrawPictureBox(PictureBox pb, int x, int y, bool drawBlue)
    {
      using (Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics())
      {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x,y, 9,9);

        if(drawBlue)
          g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, 7, 7);
      }
    }

    private void InitializePictureBox(Bitmap bmp)
    {
      pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
  }
}
```

From your example, here is my simplified suggestion. Load and cache the bitmap in a field for later use. I have added a second button2, which can be used to reload the image into the picture box to demonstrate the behaviour. Because the red rectangle is greater than the blue (9 > 7), it overwrites it when redrawing. So it is not necessary to reload the bitmap, if the position is constant. If the position changes, call `InitializePictureBox` prior to the `DrawPictureBox` call.

Comment: Thanks KBO for the reply, I do have problems with flickering of first graphic,

Comment: Thanks KBO for the reply, I do have problems with the flickering of the first graphic, Can you please guide me how do I reload the image into picture box? I mean in which part of my code?

Comment: PictureBox is already DoubleBuffered and should not show any flicker, provided all Graphics are draw in the Paint event. This is the real error in OP code.

Comment: Actually KBO in my program I don't need the second button to reload the image with the first graphic in the picture box. so can I put that initialize picture box command within my thread or in the checkbox function?

Comment: @SN25: Of course, this was only for demonstration, how the the picture box reinitialization with the bitmap works.

Comment: KBO  I have gone through your program but what if the check box is unchecked? the continuous plot display disappears?

Comment: @SN25: Yes, as you requested in your point #3 "when the check box is unchecked the second graphic stopped plotting and disappears."

Comment: Yes this is what I require

Comment: I tried your approach but at Initialize PictureBox method it gives an error at line    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;         
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
pictureBox1 was null.